# Angular 2 component not rendering on deployed version

Tags: meteor, heroku, angular, typescript

Somehow a component doesn't get rendered in the deployed version on heroku, locally it works fine though. No error, nothing - it just doesn't get rendered.

So I got a template for some navigation bar at the top which looks like this:
(Please not that I am using Angular Meteor 2.0 so importing the template like that is fine thanks to some special angular-compilers. It works.)

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import template from "./about-navigation.html";
@Component({
  selector: "about-navigation",
  template,
})
export class AboutNavigation {
}
```

It's in the app.module.ts delcarations:

```
...
import { AboutNavigation } from "./templates/about-navigation/about-navigation";
@NgModule({
  ...
  declarations: [ AppComponent,
                  About,
                  AboutNavigation,
                ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

so then here is my actual component:

```
@Component({
  selector: "about",
  template,
})
export class About {
  constructor(private router: Router) {
    });
  }
}
```

and its template:

```
<about-navigation></about-navigation>
<div class="container about-content page-transition" [@elementState]="pageTransition" >
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

This selector `<about-navigation></about-navigation>` is rendered without content though after deploying it on Heroku. 
Everything else works perfectly fine. Not one single error or warning in the console. I have no idea what it could be...

Comment: I believe in production you have enabledProdMode which hides all errors. Are you able to switch it off? Also, I'm not sure if you are able to use @ for your inputs

Comment: @LeoCaseiro '[@elementState]' is a [trigger](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/trigger-function.html) I believe

Comment: That's true, I could see it working here https://bergben.github.io/ng2-scrollimate/. I wasn't aware of that. Thanks @snolflake

Comment: Yes @LeoCaseiro the @ elementState is an animation trigger. I also tried deactivating enableProdMode, I then get the message "angular is in development mode..." so it worked for sure, but still not a single error or anything...

Comment: Hi @Benedikt. It's hard without warnings. If your heroku run your npm install, you perhaps could check each dependency. It might be a single package that is different version from your local, as well as npm and node versions. Maybe push all node_modules from local to Heroku.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the issue was with RC5 (which is the currently supported version for Angular Meteor) as seen here https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10618.
This should not be an issue in newer versions I think.

Also, I had to add

```
@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
```